# EF MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion doesn't create database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to let EF create the database on initialization as described in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx#Database%20Initializers), by configuring database initializer in the app.config file.

```
<contexts> 
  <context type="Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly"> 
    <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly], [Blogging.Migrations.Configuration, MyAssembly]], EntityFramework" /> 
  </context> 
</contexts>
```

I have also set an Interceptor to log the database output

```
<interceptors> 
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework"> 
    <parameters> 
      <parameter value="C:\Temp\LogOutput.txt"/> 
      <parameter value="true" type="System.Boolean"/> 
    </parameters> 
  </interceptor> 
</interceptors>
```

When I start the application, I get an InvalidOperationException

> Failed to set database initializer of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Blogging.BlogContext,
>   MyAssembly], [Blogging.Migrations.Configuration, MyAssembly]],
>   EntityFramework' for DbContext type 'Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly'
>   specified in the application configuration

But when I open the Log file output, it complains about not able to connect to the database with the given login.

> Failed to open connection at 2/10/2017 11:55:43 AM -05:00 with error:
>   Cannot open database "Configuration" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'XXXX'. Opened connection at 2/10/2017
>   11:55:43 AM -05:00 select cast(serverproperty('EngineEdition') as int)
>   -- Executing at 2/10/2017 11:55:43 AM -05:00
>   -- Completed in 5 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Closed connection at 2/10/2017 11:55:43 AM -05:00

The real issue is that the database doesn't exist yet, which I would like to create on app startup.

**Edit**
I am able to Update the database using Package Manager Console. There are no issues with connection strings, or the migration script.

Comment: Does the user account in the connect string have create rights? Does it create the database from the console? `Update-Database  -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase`

Comment: Yes it does work from the console. I use the configuration switch `Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName Configuration`

Comment: Any update on what you ended up using to fix this?